# Login to website using Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, web

How can I login to an Website using Swift 3? I know the username and the password.
I want to login to following site:
http://hag-lengerich.de/VPlan/subst_004.htm
Somebody told me I should use URLSession, but I cant find something for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can start working from this code:

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
let userPasswordString = "username@gmail.com:password"
let userPasswordData = userPasswordString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let base64EncodedCredential = userPasswordData!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(nil)
let authString = "Basic \(base64EncodedCredential)"
config.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = ["Authorization" : authString]
let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config)

var running = false
let url = NSURL(string: "http://hag-lengerich.de/VPlan/subst_004.htm")
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) {
  (let data, let response, let error) in
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
      let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
      println(dataString)
    }
  running = false
}

running = true
task.resume()

while running {
  println("waiting...")
  sleep(1)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesnt work. I got 2 errors:
>Use of unresolved identifier `NSURLSessionCofiguration`
> Nil is not compatible with expected argument type `Data.Base64EncodingOptions`(aka `NSData.Base64EncodingOptions`)

Comment: Now, i dont get anymore errors, but i doesnt work. Is there any other option?